# open-bank api integration with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api

I am trying to integrate Hypothekarbank Lenzburg E-bank api with ASP.NET MVC application.
I've checked the APIdocuments already but I have some problem with integration.

Where should I store the access token from the APIserver?
How can I use the access token for integration?

(If you have any sample code, that's great for me.)

Anyone for helping me?

Comment: `Where should I store the access token from the APIserver` ...somewhere secure. `How can I use the access token for integration` ... I expect it's used in the header of subsequent requests to the API in order to identify you to the server (by "subsequent" I mean after you've sent the initial authentication request, where presumably you sent your login credentials and received the access token in return). The docs should show / explain that, I would think.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply.
Where should I store the access token?
database or cookie?

Comment: Well a cookie is not really very secure as it's readable by users...do you even need the token in the front-end?

Comment: No. I need it for backend.
I want to use the access token until it is expired.

Comment: Well cookies are only really used to transmit information to the front-end, so it would make no sense to keep it there. A database should be fine. You might want to store the expiry date with it so that your app can check when it needs to renew.

Comment: Thanks so much.
One thing. how can I check if the access token is expired or not?

Comment: I'd expect normally it would come with an expiry date when you receive it, it might in a header or another property of the response. Depends on the API though